# What does roll mean here?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

Trump is on a roll!

I saw this in an advertisement for house mortgages. any idea ?

Comment: On a roll — did you look up ON A ROLL in the dictionary?

Comment: [OneLook](https://onelook.com/?w=on+a+roll&ls=a) lists more than half a dozen dictionaries that explain this phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty common phrase. It is often used to describe someone who is quickly achieving something, repetitively making a good move, experiencing a streak of success. Imagine a batsman hitting 5 sixes in a row, or Steph Curry dropping 8 three pointers in a quarter (*that wouldn't be a surprise though*).

Cambridge defines the phrase as *"experiencing a period of success or good luck."* Collins says *"if someone is on a roll, they are having great success which seems likely to continue."*

Mr. Trump can be said to  be on a roll if he is achieving a desired outcome continuously.

Also compare "in a/the groove" and "on fire".